# Different Functions for Rollover and Click Using jQuery/JS and href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry if something like this has been asked, but I've spent a long time Googling it and searching it here.
I'm trying to build a homepage for a website where the menu is along the top, rolling over the menu items should show a description of the page in the middle of the screen, which they do, and this is working. 
The problem is that because jQuery/JS is using the href tag to find the page the description is on, clicking on the menu item takes the user to a description page and not the actual page. 
I've put the description paragraphs on separate pages from those they're describing since it'd be redundant if the description showed up on both home and the page the user wants to navigate to. I've also tried display=none in the CSS to get the description to be hidden in the main page and show on the homepage, but as the description carries the CSS from the main page, it's also being hidden on the homepage.
I'll post any code if asked, I wasn't sure whether to dump it all here or just certain parts.
Thanks

Comment: We are going to need some code or somewhere to view the code. a jsfiddle would be nice or a live site.

Comment: FYI, CSS notation for display is display:none; not display=none

Comment: Thanks for the replies, just figuring out jsfiddle, 10 minutes.

Comment: I had a little trouble with JSfiddle, so hope this is okay. The full page is index.html and the code is in all the other files (just missing images and fonts.) 
http://bakers-dozen--uni.orionhub.org:8000/
And thanks for correcting my CSS notation, I always get the two mixed up.